# Error 500 internal server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

me esta generando este error una peticion ajax que hago para enviar unos parametros a un archivo.php que crea la instacia de una clase, les muestro los codigos para que miren:

Funcion guardarTweet

```
$("#guardarTweet").click(function() {
   var informacion = 
   'tweet='+$("#tweet").val()+"&"+
   'hashtag='+$("#hashtag").val()+"&"+
   'usuario='+$("#slc-usuario").val();

   console.log(informacion);
    $.ajax({
     url:"ajax/twetts.php?accion=guardar",
     method:"POST",
     data:informacion,
     success:function(){
         console.log("se guardo exitosamente");
     },
     error:function(error){
        console.error(error);
     }
  });
});
```

twetts.php tiene esto:

```
<?php
include ("../class/class-twetts.php");
switch ($_GET["accion"]) {
    case 'listar':
       echo Twetts::obtenerTwetts();
        break;

    case 'todo':
        echo Twetts::obtenerTweetts2();
        break;
    case 'guardar':
        $tweet = new Twetts(
            null,
            $_POST["tweet"],
            $_POST["hashtag"]
        );
        $tweet->guardarTweet($_POST["usuario"]);
        break;    
}
?>
```

y la funcion guardarTweet tiene esto:
mando el primer parametro en null para despues instanciarlo con un json que viene desde ../data/usuarios.json

```
public static function guardarTweet($usuarioActual){
    $tweets = json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/tweets.json"),true);
    $registroUsuarios= json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/usuarios.json"),true);
    $usuario=array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($registroUsuarios); $i++) { 
        if ($registroUsuarios[$i]["usuario"]==$usuarioActual) {
            $usuario= json_encode($registroUsuarios[$i]);
        }
    }

    $t["usuario"]=$this->$usuario;
    $t["tweet"]=$this->tweet;
    $t["hashtags"]=$this->hashtags;

    $tweets[] = $t;
    $archivo = fopen("../data/tweets.json","w");
    fwrite($archivo, json_encode($tweets));
}
```

y en consola me imprime esto :

[image: me tira ese error en el servidor , ya revise los nombres , pero no encuentro error]

[image: ahi esta lo que tiene el error POST]

Comment: si das abres la url de ese POST que dice?

Comment: Que sistema opertivo usas?

Comment: utilizo Mac os x

Comment: ya publique el error POST para que lo mires

Comment: creo que en este caso es mejor ver los registros del servidor,y ver que causa el error

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre el error , el problema es que tenia definida la funcion guardarTweet() como estatica , entonces estaba esperando un valor de retorno cuando en realidad no retornaba nada.

Gracias por su tiempo